# Why is the calculated volume wrong for extruded objects?

Tags: extrude

I have just noticed that when calculating a volume using the 3D-Print add-on I get completely different results when I extrude away material.
In the picture you will find two cuboids of identical dimensions. The left one has been scaled to those dimensions. The right one has had material extruded away. The calculated volume of the latter is off by quite a bit.
Same problem with calc_volume().
To provide a little detail: I added a plane, extruded it into the cube and selected 'DIFFERENCE'.

What is causing the calculation error?

[image: Scaled dimensions --> calculated volume correct][image: Extruded material away --> calculated volume incorrect]

Solved:
After extruding away material, your face normals are pointing in the other direction. This causes the miscalculation of calc_volume() as it uses face normals in its algorithm.
In order to fix this go into edit mode-->Mesh-->Normals-->Recalculate Inside